# Do items exist beyond Seraph or Pearlescent rarity, or beyond Overpower level eight?

Tags: borderlands-2

Can you make new rarity types that only appear in Overpower eight, or even items that exceed Overpower eight?

Comment: If you have two differents question it is better to ask them separately. I will so adress the rarity one in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

In borderlands 2 there is no other rarity than :

- White (Common)
- Green (Uncommon)
- Blue (Rare)
- Purple (Very rare)
- Orange (Unique/Legendary)
- Magenta (E-tech)
- Pink (Seraph)
- Cyan (Pearlescent)

You can not loot any other rarities in the game.

The damage range of a weapon is determined by its level. OP8 just add a multiplier to those damage aswell as to enemies life. Once you reach max level and loot weapons in OP8, you are pretty much getting the best weapons in the game in terms of damage. The only thing that you still have to worry about are the value of the special effect of legendary (like The Bee) that are not affected by OP level but are purely random.